# Sublime's menu doesn't display its shortcuts (key bindings)

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Under Ubuntu, using SublimeText 2: when clicking the "Edit" top menu, in the dropdown list, the shortcuts that are usually displayed on the right side of each feature won't show up .  I couldn't take a proper screenshot, sorry, Ubuntu doesn't want me to, but here is an example found on the web:

[image: SublimeText missing shortcuts]

So far :

- I searched in the config,
- I tried to switch my color-scheme back to default, then to some other schemes,
- I switched to SublimeText 3

None of these brought the shortcuts back.
The only workaround I figured so far is to use ALT+: it displays the dropdown list using the system's window manager (I guess), and there, the shortcuts are properly displayed.

How can I get my shortcuts back in the menu's dropdowns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the same problem with Eclipse and a solution here on SO. When I started using Sublime I tried the fix and it worked.

You need to [create a Unity Launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) as usual and make sure you put **Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= sublime** on the **Exec** line.

I'm using something like this for Ubuntu 13.10. Again, the key change is the **Exec** line:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.0.1
Name=Sublime Text 2
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor

Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= sublime
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=sublime -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```